# Mysql - query on several tables if one of them is common to two others and is not linked to the main one

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a lot of linked tables in a query, let's say the following tables are the ones that are necessarily in this conflict that is slowing down the query.

These are the ids that are linked

```
Tabla A: ventacompra(#id_ventacompra,id_factura, id_albaran)
Tabla B: factura(#id_factura,id_cliente)
Tabla C: albaran(#id_albaran,id_cliente)
Tabla D: cliente(#id_cliente)
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM ventacompra v
LEFT JOIN factura f ON v.id_factura = f.id_factura 
LEFT JOIN albaran al ON v.id_albaran = al.id_albaran 
LEFT JOIN cliente cl ON (cl.id_cliente = f.id_cliente OR  cl.id_cliente = al.id_cliente)
```

This query takes 3 seconds to execute because it has thousands of records.
If I remove the OR "cl.id_cliente = al.id_cliente" the query goes from 3 seconds to 0.220ms, but it shows the null client in the table albaran.

I don't know if I can do some type of Join so that in the case of NULL it changes to another table or some other way to accelerate the query.

____EDIT____

This is the new query and now the time is 300ms.

```
CASE 
 WHEN clf.nombre IS NOT NULL THEN clf.nombre 
 WHEN cla.nombre IS NOT NULL THEN cla.nombre
END AS nombre
LEFT JOIN cliente clf ON (clf.id_cliente = f.id_cliente and transacion='venta')
LEFT JOIN cliente cla ON (cla.id_cliente = al.id_cliente and transacion ='venta')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LEFT JOIN` when `JOIN` is what you really mean.  Ask yourself this question:  "Do I want a bunch of `NULLs` if the matching 'right-hand' table row is missing?"

Plan A:  Get rid of the un-optimizable `OR` by doing a `UNION` of two queries.  (I suspect you can/should leave out the unnecessary second table from each side.)

Plan B:

```
SELECT .. 
    FROM ventacompra 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT .. FROM factura JOIN cliente .. )
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT .. FROM albaran JOIN cliente .. )
```

I'm leaning toward Plan B, but I am *guessing* that there is always a *either* a `factura` row or `albaran`, AND *always* a `cliente` row.

If not, please provide enough data to help explain how they are related.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your help.

At the end I have put two independent join and a case that calls depending on whether it is null or not.

I have updated the main post.